# Referencing a date field without a label in JSON Python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Because the date field (e.g. 2021-03-10) nested within the "Time Series (Daily)" field doesn't have a label (e.g. "date") in the following json.dumps listing, I'm struggling to know how to reference it in Python code in order to store in an array.

```
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
    "2. Symbol": "TSCO.LON",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-03-11",
    "4. Output Size": "Full size",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2021-03-11": {
        "1. open": "222.8",
        "2. high": "223.3",
        "3. low": "219.6",
        "4. close": "220.0",
        "5. adjusted close": "220.0",
        "6. volume": "18356667",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0"
    },
    "2021-03-10": {
        "1. open": "221.7",
        "2. high": "223.063",
        "3. low": "219.68",
        "4. close": "222.2",
        "5. adjusted close": "222.2",
        "6. volume": "18970902",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0"``
```

I would normally expect to use something like this:

```
for item in data['Time Series (Daily)']:
    dates.append(item['date'])
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What you described is right.  "item" will be the date strings.  Do `dates.append( item )`.  You don't even need a loop.  If `dates` is a list, do `dates.extend( data['Time Series (Daily)'].keys() )`

Comment: As a side-note, if you can get the other side to omit the numbers ("1. " etc) from the keys, it'll probably be better in the long run...

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
dates = data['Time Series (Daily)'].keys()
```

Answer to you question in the comments:

```
result = list(data['Time Series (Daily)'].items())
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you - that works, but how do I collect the nested key/values beneath the date value, e.g. "1. open". I'm trying to produce a list of (date, value) throughout the range of dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
dates = data['Time Series (Daily)'].items()
```

this will result in returning an iterator of all the pairs of key,value in your time series.